Python asyncio: client sends string commands to server concatenated
I am very new with asyncio, I am trying to setup a server on remote mashine (win) which asynchronously receives string commands and executes them in cmd.
I have a simple client side:
import asyncio
import socket


async def send_task(skt: socket.socket, msg):
    skt.send(str.encode(msg))
    print('task sent')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def main(skt: socket.socket, myloop):
    tasks = [
        myloop.create_task(send_task(skt, r'dir D:\Users\sandbox')),
        myloop.create_task(send_task(skt, r'D: && cd D:\Users\sandbox && run.bat')),
        myloop.create_task(send_task(skt, r'copy D:\Users\sandbox\model1.mesh D:\Users\Zharov\SPLAV\copied_model1.mesh'))
    ]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)


sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.7.42', 50182))

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(main(sock, loop))

And a simple server side:
import asyncio
import subprocess as sb
import socket
import time


async def executor(cmd):
    print('start executing job %s' % cmd.decode('cp1251'))
    proc = sb.Popen(cmd.decode('cp1251'), shell=True, stdout=sb.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    print(stdout.decode('cp1251'))
    if stderr:
        print(stderr.decode('cp1251'))
    print('------------------------------------------')


async def main():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('', 0))
    print('port: %d' % sock.getsockname()[1])
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('connected:', addr)
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < 100:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data:
            await executor(data)
    conn.close()


asyncio.run(main())

The 'dir' command gets executed fine, but the second and the third command strings received concatenated by server, thats piece of stdout of executor() coroutine:
start executing job D: && cd D:\Users\sandbox && run.batcopy D:\Users\sandbox\model1.mesh D:\Users\SPLAV\copied_model1.mesh

It happens in 100% of times.

TCP is a byte stream, not a stream of messages. There is no kind of implicit message boundary. There is no 1:1 relationship between send and recv, i.e. data can be combined or split for optimal underlying transport. If you need message semantics, then you need to implement it yourself on top of TCP.

Never ever send raw commands. It's a big security flaw. Construct command on server side from bunch of arguments.
